# How to encode an array of structs to store it in memory?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have a controller and I need to store in flash memory an array of structs, which can have 2000+ items.

What is the best way to encode the array and save it in the flash memory?

Is this good enough?

```
char b[sizeof(array)]; 
memcpy(b, &array, sizeof(array));
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `memcpy` to copy arbitrary data is dangerous because `memcpy` just copies memory. It does not respect the needs of any objects in that memory. For example, `memcpy` a `std::string` and watch the fun ensue. You could have two `std::string`s pointing to the same dynamic  allocation. You could have two `string`s pointing to the small string optimization buffer inside one of the `string`s. All sorts of chaos is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by saving it in memory? You have an array of structs, which is already in memory. The code you've shown us just copies all the bytes into another location.

Comment: What you have is good enough **only** [if the elements of `array` are _TriviallyCopyable_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) and you are ensuring that no pointers dangle.  Otherwise, you have Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Kevin It is a flash memory and at some point the controller will restart and I need to save the information of my array so that when it restarts I'm able to decode and get the information.

Comment: Depends completely on the contents of `array`.

Comment: @john each structure in the array have only 3 items (2 floats and 1 int).

Comment: @xCasal Then I don't see any problem.

Comment: Unrelated: Since the data is dead simple, you might not have to bother with `b` at all. If you can `memcpy` `array` into `b` safely, you should be able to directly write `array` to the flash.

Comment: Side note: For the benefit of future askers, you should edit the question to include the definition of the structure or even the fact that the contents are all trivially copiable. This keeps all of the important information in one place.

Comment: Depends on your Flash memory interface.  If your Flash Memory uses a serial access method (like SPI), you can't use `memcpy`.  The `memcpy` only works on memory devices that use parallel addressing.  Also, remember that you have unlock one or more sectors, erase them, then start programming and finally lock the Flash.  I would not use `memcpy` with a Flash Memory device; not worth the hassle.  Besides, if you write your own, you can use specialized assembly instructions that may help data transfer speeds.

Comment: internal flash memory of MCU I worked with (ATmega, espressif, samd21, nrf5, stm32) requires to enable writing and clear the page or sector before writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char b[sizeof(array)]; 
memcpy(b, &array, sizeof(array));
```

This will give you a bit-by-bit identical copy of the array. If you then write that to flash using whatever interface you have to the flash then you might as well just cast the original array to `std::byte` and write it directly.

The problem comes when the objects in the array are not trivially copyable. Anything with pointers (like `std::string` for example) will not work. You would have to serialize before writing.

You might actually want to do that even with just fundamental types in a struct because the struct might contain padding. The size of the struct might be larger than the size of the data it contains. With 2000+ objects in the array even saving 1 byte would save you 2000 byte of flash every time your write. You could also use variable length encoding if you for example have 4 bytes ints that are mostly small numbers.

Comment: the built-in flash memory of the MCU is in the same address space as RAM. the target address of the memcpy is in flash

Comment: A locally declared `char b[sizeof(array)];` though will be on the stack and not in flash.